# Storing objects in multiple NSArrays

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, foundation

I 'm learning about `Objective - C` by developing a contacts app. I'm not using `Core data` or the `Address book API`, as this is just for learning. So each contact is an object which is stored in a master `NSArray`. Users can create groups of contacts where each group stores the appropriate contact objects in an `NSArray`. The problem I'm facing is when a contact is deleted from the master array , I have to manually remove it from all the groups as `NSArray` retains its objects. Is there a better way around this?

Comment: are u copying the same object in different groups..?

Comment: yes , why is that a bad approach ? It would solve the consistency problems.

Answer (score 0):

As you are learning, i suggest:

**Simple:**
Have your application only contacts list, adding/editing/deleting a contact  from a single master list. You can also save & retrieve list from plist in documents directory.

You will be learning: plist, tableView, navigation, viewControllers, maintaining data from & within array.

**Realtime:**
You can use a sqlite database, with 4-5 tables. Each having Contacts, Groups, Address, Website and many other if you like to have. All the tables with interlinked with a reference of row id's. Which definitely help you learn many things, apart from the above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Dont copy objects into multiple arrays. Add the same object to multiple arrays using the same pointer to the original object.  Maintain pointers to the arrays and remove the same object from all the arrays at once.  If you want to implement isEqual make it use == pointer equality.

Copying the same object for the purposes of storing in collections only creates headaches for yourself.  Immutability is a nice feature, but actual identity across the system is a better one especially in a pointer based language.

Comment: This is what I'm doing now . I was thinking maybe use something like notifications to so the contact group object could remove it from its list all on its own . But the userinfo dict *copies* the object passed into it .